# Google Action is Deployed but didn't received any mail regarding claim for rewards.?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-developers-console, google-console-developer

I deployed my action few days ago and it has been successfully deployed named as "My own Data Scientist" but didn't receive any mail from google for rewards or anything.

Answer (score 2):

The community program is no longer [active](https://developers.google.com/assistant/community/developer-community-program), Google has paused the program a couple months ago. If you already received an email of a reward you can still retrieve it till 23rd of December 2019, but if you haven't received anything you won't be able get any rewards anymore.